# Why do the Mars pictures sent by Viking 2 and the Chinese Lander show quite different landscapes of the same Utopia Planitia?

Tags: mars, viking, tianwen-1

The photos transmitted by the Viking 2 lander and those taken by the Chinese rover show quite different landscapes. They do not corroborate each other, also they should look similar, as long as they present the same Utopia Planitia. So, there exist no mutual independent confirmation of landings in the above mention plain, up to the present moment.

> "Utopia Planitia is a large plain within Utopia, the largest
> recognized impact basin on Mars and in the Solar System with an
> estimated diameter of 3300 km. It is the Martian region where the
> Viking 2 lander touched down and began exploring on September 3, 1976,
> and the Zhurong rover touched down on 14 May, 2021, as a part of the
> Tianwen-1 mission." [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_Planitia)

**USA**

[image]

Utopia Planitia. Image taken by Viking 2 US Lander.

**China**

[image]

[image]

> "The first photograph, a black and white image, was taken by an
> obstacle avoidance camera installed in front of the Mars rover. The
> image shows that a ramp on the lander has been extended to the surface
> of Mars. The terrain of the rover's forward direction is clearly
> visible in the image, and the horizon of Mars appears curved due to
> the wide-angle lens.
>
> The second image, a color photo, was taken by the navigation camera
> fitted to the rear of the rover. The rover's solar panels and antenna
> are seen unfolded, and the red soil and rocks on the Martian surface
> are clearly visible in the image."
>
> Source: [China's Tianwen-1 probe sends back Mars landing visuals -
> Date：2021-05-19](http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/english/n6465652/n6465653/c6812028/content.html)

Comment: ...you realize Utopia Planitia is a few thousand km across, right?

Comment: Since NASA's Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter has [imaged many other landers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter#Other_spacecraft) it would be a risky fraud to attempt.

Comment: `-1` Stack Exchange questions need to be *questions*. This is a conspiracy theory-pushing argument only pretending to be a question. "They do not corroborate each other, also they should look similar, as long as they present the same Utopia Planitia. So, there exist no mutual independent confirmation of landings in the above mention plain, up to the present moment." You can't use Stack Exchange questions to "announce things" or push theories. Can you edit your post and remove the part I've quoted and simply ask a question? Otherwise this may be heavily down voted and/or closed.

Comment: @uhoh: This 'question' was previously an 'answer' (quotes intentional) to another question.  That previous question was also pushing some conspiracy theory, inevitably.

Comment: @tfb I'd read recently about a conspiracy theory circulating in Chinese social media that the US Moon landings were fake, and China would be first. Although prefaced by "evil empire" characterizations, the "internet minders" there did stamp out the conspiracy theories, saying that despite the US being inherently inferior and doomed to collapse, they did land on the Moon. So we here in Stack Exchange can return the favor (minus the color) and stamp out these as well. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Utopia Planitia has a diameter of [about $3300\,\mathrm{km}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_Planitia).  That means its area is around $8.5\times 10^6\,\mathrm{km^2}$.  The area of the 48 contiguous states of the US is about $8.1\times 10^6\,\mathrm{km^2}$: this feature is about 5% bigger than *the entire 48 contiguous states of the US*.

We know that Zhurong landed something like $1700\,\mathrm{km}$ from Viking 2.

It would be deeply astonishing if the terrain over the vast area of Utopia Planitia was *anything like* uniform.  It would be as astonishing as if, say, the terrain in Kansas was the same as it is in the Rockies (I have not visited either region but I am assured they are not similar), or as if the terrain in Norfolk was the same as Tignes (hint: people ski in Tignes, they din't in Norfolk)

And, entirely unsurprisingly, the terrain is not, in fact, uniform.

Answer (score 6):

Pick any area or larger crater on Mars (Hellas, Isidis, Elysium, Argyre...) and go to inspect them under high res visible imaging on Google Maps Mars, or better on the 3-D version of that, Google Earth and then Mars.

You will find that any of those regions contains a large variety of terrains on the scales of tens to 100s kms, smooth ones, chaos terrains, mesas, dune fields etc.

So no, there is absolutely no need for them to look similar.

Answer (score 4):

Utopia Planitia is a [large plain, some 3560km in diameter](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Feature/6260). That's only a little less than the distance from New York to Seattle, so a variety of terrains within it shouldn't be surprising.

I didn't find coordinates for the actual landing site of the Zhurong rover, however the [target site was reported earlier](https://www.space.com/china-mars-rover-tianwen-1-landing-site), which is 1758km from the Viking 2 location. So they aren't at all close neighbours.